# After Insert on one table, depending on quantity depends on how many entries in another table- MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql

So I have a strange question. I have two tables:

Table 1:

Id, grade1, grade2, grade 3, quantity

Table 2:

Id, stage, grade

Now- when something is entered into table 1 – Say 1,2, 1, 0, 3 – I need it to enter 3 entries into table two as follows:

```
Id, stage, grade
1, 0, 1
2, 0, 1
3, 0, 2
```

So depending what is entered into quantity in table 1, after this is inserted, depends on how many records are entered into table two, and depending on what numbers are entered into table 1, depends on what grade they get given in table 2.

I need this to potentially be done within a trigger. I don't really know how I would approach something like this. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: I don't see how you get from 1,2,1,0,3 to the stage and grade values in table 2 given that there is there is only 1 grade 1 in table 1

Comment: Hi. Basically say if you entered (Grade1) 2, (Grade2) 1, (Grade3) 0, (Quantity) 3 into table 1, the output to table two would be as above. It would enter 3 separate entries into table 2, 2 with a grade as 1, and 1 with a grade as 2.

Comment: Note that enumerated column names (above, say, 2) are frequently a sign of poor schema design

Comment: @Strawberry- so what would be a better approach but with the same output do you think?

Comment: ' It would enter 3 separate entries into table 2, 2 with a grade as 1, and 1 with a grade as 2.' I guess quantity = 3 then 3 rows but I have no idea what the ids in table2 should start from mwhy all 3 should get a stage = 0 and 2 should get a grade 1 and 1 should get a grade 2 - is there any logic you can describe and can you also describe what happens if you have a quantity of 2. Examples of the use cases and their outcomes would help